# How can I unbind a key from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, system-settings

I accidentally bound my <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key to change the keyboard language, I don't even remember how I did that. Is there a way that I can unbind this key? Maybe in Ubuntu settings? I don`t know, feels like I tried everything I know.

I mean, I tried going to the keyboard shortcuts, but it was not useful.

Comment: did you try `gnome-tweaks`?? gnome-tweaks is not installed by default.

Comment: Which key is it really?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do it on Settings>Devices>Keyboard? Or with `xbindkeys`?

Comment: its the Right Alt @mikewhatever

Comment: i have gnome-tweaks installed, but how that helps me @UnKNOWn ?

Comment: yeah, i`m sure @PabloBianchi i reseted and all that but idk, it`s something on the system, i`m starting to think maybe it`s on the BIOS, idk... im complety lost on this one lol

Comment: Guys, i discovered something more. When i press the key right alt it activates the Scroll Lock, i have no idea why, i think i binded that when i had a error on my computer and the error sugested that i use right alt as a shortcut, unfortunally i dont remember much details about it. And i`m sure its something Ubuntu related because it works just fine on Windows (i have dual boot). Please! May someone helpe me =(